# SageMaker TensorFlow Estimator source code S3 upload path

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-s3, upload, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using the SageMaker TensorFlow estimator for training, and specifying an output path for my model artifacts with the `output_path` argument, with a value of `s3://<bucket>/<prefix>/`.

After model training, a directory named `<training_job_name>/output` is created in the specified `output_path`.

The issue I'm having is, the source code that's used for training is also uploaded to S3 by default, but instead of being placed in `s3://<bucket>/<prefix>/<training_job_name>/source`, it's placed in `s3://<bucket>/<training_job_name>/source`.

So how can I specify the S3 upload path for the training job's source code in order to make it use the bucket AND prefix name of `output_path`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the “code_location” argument: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/estimators.html to specify the location for the source code?

Below is a snippet code example that use code_location

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

code-path = "s3://<bucket>/<prefix>"
output-path = "s3://<bucket>/<prefix>"

abalone_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='abalone.py',
                           role=role,
                           framework_version='1.12.0',
                           training_steps= 100, 
                           image_name=image,
                           evaluation_steps= 100,
                           hyperparameters={'learning_rate': 0.001},
                           train_instance_count=1,
                           train_instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
                           code_location= code-path,
                           output_path = output-path,
                           base_job_name='my-job-name'
                           )
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the code_location parameter shown by @user3458797 is the correct answer.

The output_path only configures the S3 location for saving the training result (model artifacts and output files).

https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/estimators.html

Your training script won't be saved in the "output_path" unless you move the file into /opt/ml/model during the training or you use the code_location parameter.

Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify.